# Select a list of options to display according to value of radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, radio-button

I want to display only some options in a select according to the value of radio buttons. As I retrieve data from databases (MYSQL PDO), I'll simplify my code.

```
<input type="radio" name="type_rapport" value="v" id="r_v" /><label for="r_v">RV</label>
<input type="radio" name="type_rapport" value="f" id="r_f" /><label for="r_f">RF</label>
<input type="radio" name="type_rapport" value="g" id="r_g" /><label for="r_g">RG</label>

<select>
    <option value="rv1">RV1</option>
    <option value="rv2">RV2</option>
    <option value="rf1">RF1</option>
    <option value="rf2">RF2</option>
    <option value="rg1">RG1</option>
    <option value="rg2">RG2</option>
</select>
```

When RV is selected, only the options "rv1" and "rv2" should be displayed (and so on). I tried different solutions, but unfortunately I didn't succeed.

Javascript/Jquery will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep _Javascript/Jquery will be appreciated._ Show us some.

Comment: I tried with 3 different divs with a select inside with this code :

    var n=document.getElementsByName(e.name);
    document.getElementById('divV').className=(n[0].checked)?'show':'hidden';
    document.getElementById('divF').className=(n[1].checked)?'show':'hidden';
    document.getElementById('divG').className=(n[2].checked)?'show':'hidden';

But as I'm using the get method in my form, I'm receiving 3 vars.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jQuery :

```
$(function(){
     $('select').prop('disabled',true);//disable select box    
    $('[name=type_rapport]').change(function(){
     $('select').removeProp('disabled'); // enable select box
     var valueRadio = $(this).val();
     $('select option').hide();
     $('select option[value^="r'+valueRadio+'"]').show();
        $('select option[value^="r'+valueRadio+'"]:first').prop('selected',true);
    });
  });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLdk/18/)**

Comment: Thank you for your interest. But in your code, all the options are displayed, unfortunately.

Comment: @Aknorw, you mean when page loads all options visible? Then in this case you need to pre-select radio button and show respective option.

Comment: I'd like to have a disabled select when no radio is selected, then only display several options according to the value of the radio buttons.

Comment: @Aknorw, but you did not mentioned this in your question. Anyways, I have updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: Sorry about that then, thought I mentioned it. This is almost done with your updated code. How can I hide the rf and rg options when selecting RF ?

Comment: ' hide the rf and rg options when selecting RF', did not get you. When you select RF then you want to hide other options right?

Comment: Pseudo code :
if (value=v) then show(rv1,rv2) and hide(rf1,rf2,rg1,rg2)
Same for the other radios

Comment: Have you checked the 'working demo' link provided in my answer? It works as you said. Above code is doing the same thing as you mentioned. (refresh this page first)

Comment: No, you can still select RV1 or RV2 even if you've selected RF or RG.

Answer (score 0):

your jquery

```
$('.rd').on('change',function(){
  var last='r'+$(this).val();

  $('select > option').hide();
  $('select > option[value^="'+last+'"]').show();
   $("select  option").filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr('value') == last+'1';
    }).attr('selected', true);

});


<input type="radio" name="type_rapport" class="rd" value="v" id="r_v" /><label for="r_v">RV</label>
<input type="radio" name="type_rapport" class="rd" value="f" id="r_f" /><label for="r_f">RF</label>
<input type="radio" name="type_rapport" class="rd" value="g" id="r_g" /><label for="r_g">RG</label>

<select>
    <option value="rv1">RV1</option>
    <option value="rv2">RV2</option>
    <option value="rf1">RF1</option>
    <option value="rf2">RF2</option>
    <option value="rg1">RG1</option>
    <option value="rg2">RG2</option>
</select>
```

[**DEMO**](http://liveweave.com/Ha97kN)

[**DEMO2**](http://liveweave.com/HbP2F4)